# ASP.Net using RadioButtonList / CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, controls

I am finishing up a program for my ASP.Net class for an ice cream shop done as a web app, the main page looks like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bya5.jpg). I need two classes for the Ice Cream ordering:

```
IceCreamOrder
IceCreamOrderList
```

currently the only code in my IceCreamOrderList class is

```
public class IceCreamOrderList
{
    List<IceCreamOrder> ICorders = new List<IceCreamOrder>();

    public List<IceCreamOrder> ListofOrders { get { return ICorders; } }

    public void Add(IceCreamOrder data) { ICorders.Add(data); }
```

and nothing in the IceCreamOrder class. My code on/around the Submit Order button [IS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJAEx.jpg)

I've done a simpler program that was just taking text entered into a textbox and adding to a list, but my biggest problem is figuring out how to determine what control is set to true and then add them into a list. I have names for each of the controls as follows:

```
FlavorsList
ToppingsList
ServeList
```

Any help and guidance toward finishing this would be most greatly appreciated. and Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already using `RadioButtonList` and `CheckBoxList` into your order page, you should change event handler `btnSubmit_Click` as follows:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IceCreamOrder order = new IceCreamOrder();
        order.Flavor = FlavorsList.SelectedValue;
        foreach (ListItem listItem in ToppingsList.Items)
        {
            if (listItem.Selected)
                order.Toppings.Add(listItem.Value);
        }
        order.Serve = ServeList.SelectedValue;
        // add order to order list
    }

    public class IceCreamOrder
    {
        public string Flavor { get; set; }
        public List<string> Toppings { get; set; }
        public string Serve { get; set; }

        public IceCreamOrder()
        {
            Toppings = new List<string>();
        }
    }
```